# Flatten list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (sample) as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India', 'China', 'Nepal'],
          'Habitat':[[{'city1':'Ind1','city2':'Ind2'},{'town1':'IndT1','town2':'IndT2'}],
                     [{'city1':'Chi1','city2':'Chi2'},{'town1':'ChiT1','town2':'ChiT2'}],
                     [{'city1':'Nep1','city2':'Nep2'},{'town1':'NepT1','town2':'NepT2'}]],
            'num':[1,2,3]
          })
```

df

```
    Country                                                           Habitat   num
0   India   [{'city1':'Ind1','city2':'Ind2'},{'town1':'IndT1','town2':'IndT2'}] 1
1   China   [{'city1':'Chi1','city2':'Chi2'},{'town1':'ChiT1','town2':'ChiT2'}] 2
2   Nepal   [{'city1':'Nep1','city2':'Nep2'},{'town1':'NepT1','town2':'NepT2'}] 3
```

I need to flatten this out in this format.

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India', 'China', 'Nepal'],
          'Habitat.city1':['Ind1','Chi1','Nep1'],
            'Habitat.city2':['Ind2','Chi2','Nep2'],
            'Habitat.town1':['IndT1','ChiT1','NepT1'],
            'Habitat.town2':['IndT2','ChiT2','NepT2'],
            'num':[1,2,3]
          })
```

result_df

```
    Country Habitat.city1   Habitat.city2   Habitat.town1   Habitat.town2   num
    India       Ind1            Ind2            IndT1           IndT2       1
    China       Chi1            Chi2            ChiT1           ChiT2       2
    Nepal       Nep1            Nep2            NepT1           NepT2       3
```

I have tried `pd.json_normalize(df.explode('Habitat')['Habitat])` but it creates new rows which I do not need.

---

My observation:
Some form of groupby and transpose that can properly build on `pd.json_normalize(df.explode('Habitat')['Habitat])` could solve my problem but so far I have not had any luck

---

Comment: Is this coming for a source JSON, can we flatten before the creation of this dataframe?

Comment: The source is a json file. But the files can get huge, so iterating per row may get very expensive

Comment: working with the json file, before dumping into Pandas should be more performant

Answer (score 5):

Let us use `ChainMap` to merge the list of dictionaries in each row, then create a new dataframe and `join` back with original dataframe

```
from itertools import starmap
from collections import ChainMap

h = pd.DataFrame(starmap(ChainMap, df['Habitat']), df.index)
df.join(h.add_prefix('Habitat.'))
```

---

```
  Country                                                                     Habitat  num Habitat.city1 Habitat.city2 Habitat.town1 Habitat.town2
0   India  [{'city1': 'Ind1', 'city2': 'Ind2'}, {'town1': 'IndT1', 'town2': 'IndT2'}]    1          Ind1          Ind2         IndT1         IndT2
1   China  [{'city1': 'Chi1', 'city2': 'Chi2'}, {'town1': 'ChiT1', 'town2': 'ChiT2'}]    2          Chi1          Chi2         ChiT1         ChiT2
2   Nepal  [{'city1': 'Nep1', 'city2': 'Nep2'}, {'town1': 'NepT1', 'town2': 'NepT2'}]    3          Nep1          Nep2         NepT1         NepT2
```

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.9+ you can use the dictionary [union](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/), as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import or_
from itertools import starmap
    
    
flat = pd.DataFrame(starmap(or_, df['Habitat']), df.index).add_prefix('Habitat.')
res = pd.concat([df.drop(labels=['Habitat'], axis=1), flat], axis=1)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
Country  num Habitat.city1 Habitat.city2 Habitat.town1 Habitat.town2
0   India    1          Ind1          Ind2         IndT1         IndT2
1   China    2          Chi1          Chi2         ChiT1         ChiT2
2   Nepal    3          Nep1          Nep2         NepT1         NepT2
```

The operator [`or_`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.or_) will call the `|` implementation of the objects under-the-hood, from the documentation:

> Return the bitwise or of a and b.

For the case of dictionaries the `|` is the union. For more information on how to merge two dictionaries see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/4001592).

An alternative solution that works for any number of dictionaries, is to use `functools.reduce`:

```
import pandas as pd
from operator import or_
from functools import reduce, partial

merge = partial(reduce, or_)

flat = pd.DataFrame(map(merge, df['Habitat']), df.index).add_prefix('Habitat.')
res = pd.concat([df.drop(labels=['Habitat'], axis=1), flat], axis=1)
```

For more information see [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).